# Getting weird output reading from stdin

Tags: c, linux, unix

So what i'm trying to do is repeat the input from keyboard to stdout. It must use read/write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
int  main() {
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    while (1)
       if (read(0, buffer,  sizeof(buffer))) 
             write(1, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
         return 0;
}
```

If I type "hello" it creates a new line with a bunch of weird symbols & letters and on another new line it will say "hello"

Comment: `write` will write all of the bytes specified by the third parameter (`sizeof(buffer)`). The buffer is not necessarially full, so you need to use the return value of `read` to figure out how many bytes there are to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should, save the return value of `read()` and write only that amount which is what `read()` really read.

Your code is also too confusing and doesn't make a lot of sense, your `while` loop should have a condition and there is inhertently one in such a program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024
int  
main(void) 
{
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    ssize_t length;
    while ((length = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer,  sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, length); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Quick question why did you use `STD_INFILENO` instead of 0?

Comment: It's `STDIN_FILENO` and because it's a macro that expands to the *stdin* file number or `0`, but using the macro makes the code more readable.